# To fire trigger only when there is change in field of IsActive__c of account

Tags: apex, trigger, account

Hi all I have written a trigger but i want it to fire only when there is update in IsActive field else it should not fire so please could you help me
This is my trigger

```
public static void processAccounts(Map<Id, Account> accMap,Map<Id, Account> accoldMap,LIst<Account>accList) {

    Boolean status;
    Set<Id> accountsWithNew = new Set<Id>();
    Set<Id> accountsWithRenew = new Set<Id>();
    List<Contact> contactsToCheck =[SELECT Id, 
                                           Type__c,
                                           AccountId
                                    FROM Contact 
                                    WHERE (Type__c = 'New' OR Type__c = 'Renew') 
                                    AND Accountid IN :accMap.keySet()];
    for (Contact c : contactsToCheck) {  
        if (c.Type__c == 'New') {
            accountsWithNew.add(c.AccountId);
        } else if (c.Type__c == 'Renew') {
            accountsWithRenew.add(c.AccountId);
        }

    }

    for (Account acc_i : accMap.values()) {
        /*Boolean hasNewCon = accountsWithNew.contains(acc_i.Id);
        Boolean hasRenewCon = accountsWithRenew.contains(acc_i.Id);
        if(acc_i.IsActive__c==true){
        if (hasNewCon && hasRenewCon) {*/
        if(accountsWithNew.contains(acc_i.Id) && accountsWithRenew.contains(acc_i.Id)){
            status=true;
        }
        if(acc_i.IsActive__c==true){
            if(status==true){
                System.debug('You can update');
                acc_i.IsActive__c = true;
            } else {
                acc_i.addError('You should have at least 1 contact of type new and 1 of type renew');
                acc_i.IsActive__c = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not really clear what you're looking to do because the code you posted isn't a trigger. In short, in your trigger you can see the old versus new value of isActive to compare when it changes.

Comment: this is a handler class for my trigger

Answer (score 2):

You passed the maps into your handler code so you really just need to compare them by using the acc ID as the key between the two maps

```
 for (Account acc_i : accMap.values()) {
        if(acc_i.IsActive__c==true && acc_i.IsActive__c != accoldMap.get(acc_i.Id).IsActive__c){
                System.debug('You can update');
                acc_i.IsActive__c = true;
            } else {
                acc_i.addError('You should have at least 1 contact of type new and 1 of type renew');
                acc_i.IsActive__c = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I tried it but it is not working for bulk

Comment: You'll need to provide more info on any errors you get or what doesn't work. Doesn't mean you can just copy and paste whatever I provide and hope it works if you don't try to learn/understand it

Comment: Towards the bottom of [answer], there's a section that says "Not all questions can or should be answered" that I, myself, take to heart. Sure, this is a pretty easy question to answer, but the signs point to someone who wants people to do their work for them. Still, +1 from me.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your trigger to fire only when `IsActive__c` is changed to `true`, then you will have to check for two conditions.

1. Old value of `IsActive__c` is not same as new value of `IsActive__c`
2. New value of `IsActive__c` is `true`

So that is how your condition should be, so replace below code

```
if(acc_i.IsActive__c==true)
```

with

```
if(acc.IsActive__c != accoldMap.get(acc.Id).IsActive__c && acc_i.IsActive__c==true)
```

Comment: I tried but it is not working for bulk can u please give me some other solution

Comment: it is only executing first record successfully then it is showing error

Comment: What error is it showing ? Please edit your post and mention the error so that community can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try 'after update':

```
trigger AccountTrigger on Account(  after update){  

    if( Trigger.isAfter && Trigger.isUpdate){ 
        AccountTriggerHelper.handleAfterUpdate(Trigger.newMap, Trigger.oldMap);
    }    
}

public with sharing class AccountTriggerHelper{

    public static void handleAfterUpdate(Map <Id, Account> newMap, Map<Id,Account> oldMap){
        Map <Id, Account> accsToUpdateById = new Map <Id, Account>();
        for (Account newAcc: newMap.values()){
            if( newAcc.IsActive__c != oldMap.get(newAcc.Id).IsActive__c ){
                accsToUpdateById.put( newAcc.Id, newAcc ); 
                // your code: do something with accsToUpdateById  or each element
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take a look at [answer]. The best answers tend to explain _how_ to solve the problem, as well as _why_ the solution should work. The idea is that this helps people understand the underlying problem, and how to recognize and solve similar issues in the future.

Comment: The key part of the solution here is using oldMap to do a comparison. I don't think moving to an `after` trigger really makes any positive difference here. It would mean you'd need to perform DML and worry about recursion if you want to update a field on a record in `trigger.new`/`trigger.newMap`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, I have solved the issue